# "Take attention away"... is it a common phrase in English?

Tags: expressions

Is the expression *take attention away* something that sounds okay in English? I'm a Portuguese speaker, so *tirar atenção* is a normal expression, so I don't know to what extent I'm writing a natural English expression or just letting Portuguese influence my foreign language knowledge. Let me give you an example:

"The pursuit of photorealism often takes attention away from other aspects of game design."

Does this sound natural, or would there be any other way to convey the same meaning?

Comment: Your use of _take attention away_ sounds perfectly fine to my ear (west coast US).  _Diverts_, as @lbf suggested is also acceptable, though it sounds more formal to me.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn concur. Sounds fine to me. Northeast US.

Answer (score 1):

**divert**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/divert) idiomatic

> divert (someone or something) from (someone or something) To induce
>   someone or something to change course or direct their attention to
>   something else.

Consider:

> The pursuit of photo-realism often diverts attention away from other
>   aspects of game design."

The OED list 11 examples of **diverting attention**, two examples of **taking attention**.

Comment: I would also suggest 'distract attention'

Comment: @Kate or simply 'disract'